# Defining a String#prev method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, encoding

I have seen Ruby's String#next can handle non ASCII characters.
Saying that I know English, Bengali and Hindi:

```
> 'a'.next    # => "b"
> 'ক'.next    # => "খ"
> 'क'.next    # => "ख"
```

Which is right.

Now I want to dynamically define a `prev` method to the String class.
I can do this:

```
String.define_method(:prev) { slice(0..-2) + slice(-1).ord.-(1).chr }
> 'hit'.prev    # => "his"
> 'b'.prev      # => "a"

> 'ख'.prev
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /home/sourav/.irb:351:in `<main>'
        3: from (irb):17
        2: from (irb):11:in `block in irb_binding'
        1: from (irb):11:in `chr'
RangeError (2325 out of char range)
```

But it should return the followings:

```
> 'b'.prev     # => "a"
> 'ख'.prev    # => "क"
> 'খ'.prev    # => "ক"
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going to have to pass the encoding for that because the default external encoding is `US-ASCII`.

Changing `chr` to `chr('UTF-8')` will result in `"\u0915"` which is correct for the symbol prior to `'ख'`